# How can I view exposure matching my camera settings in the viewfinder of my Canon 70D?

Tags: canon, viewfinder, exposure-preview

I'm new to 70D, coming from a Fuji mirrorless system. I'm used to being able to see my exposure change in my viewfinder as I change settings on my camera. I cannot figure out how to make the 70D do this. Can anyone help and offer guidance?

Thanks

Comment: Do you talk about histogram? Or about exposure indicator?

Answer (score 2):

See [What is it called when aperture and exposure are previewed on the LCD screen before the shot is taken?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/87906/what-is-it-called-when-aperture-and-exposure-are-previewed-on-the-lcd-screen-bef/87910#87910) — Canon calls this feature "Exposure Simulation", or `EXP. Sim`. Of course, you can't enable it in the *viewfinder*, since the viewfinder is showing you actual light coming in through the lens directly — it's not an EVF like in you Fujifilm. But, you can enable it in "Live View" mode for the rear LCD. (See page 230 of your manual.)

Answer (score 1):

Shutter speed and ISO can't (for now?) be simulated when looking through an optical viewfinder. BUT you can see aperture variation using the DoF preview button on your lens.

Related:

- [Why can't I see bokeh in the viewfinder?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21152/why-cant-i-see-bokeh-in-the-viewfinder)
- [Why is the depth-of-field preview in the optical viewfinder of my Canon 500D inaccurate?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/why-is-the-depth-of-field-preview-in-the-optical-viewfinder-of-my-canon-500d-ina)